# I Have an XML file saved as a txt file I am trying to extract data from it to display it using Python

Tags: python, parsing

The data is in this format "25.91
I have multiple rows this way

I'm trying to extract the numeric characters data 25.91
the 25.91

I've tried writing code for this but something just doesn't add up.

```
import re
myfile = open("BOMR1_.txt")
for line in myfile:
    line=line.rstrip()
    StartMP = re.findall(r'^xml.*<FROM>([0-9.]+)', line)
    if len(StartMP)> 0:
        Print (StartMP)
```

I would like to view the Data like 
Startmp=25.91 and so on

Comment: Use an actual XML parser.  Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use regular expressions to parse hierarchical data formats like XML.  See [this fantastic article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) on the matter for more details on why regular expression processors aren't in and of themselves parsers.

A key passage from that article reads:

> Regular expressions are not Parsers. Although you can do some amazing
>   things with regular expressions, they are weak at balanced tag
>   matching. Some regex variants have balanced matching, but it is
>   clearly a hack – and a nasty one. You can often make it kinda-sorta
>   work, as I have in the sanitize routine. But no matter how clever your
>   regex, don't delude yourself: it is in no way, shape or form a
>   substitute for a real live parser.